# Error #1009 and randomInterval() in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I used a given code from  animation templates for scripted rain. So my code looks like this:

```
stop();


// Number of symbols to add.
const NUM_SYMBOLS:uint = 175;

var symbolsArray:Array = [];
var idx:uint;
var drop:Rain;

for (idx = 0; idx < NUM_SYMBOLS; idx++) {
    drop = new Rain();
    addChild(drop);
    symbolsArray.push(drop);
    // Call randomInterval() after 0 to a given ms.
    setTimeout(randomInterval, int(Math.random() * 10000), drop);
}

function randomInterval(target:Rain):void {

    // Set the current Rain instance's x and y property 
    target.x = Math.random()* 800-50;
    target.y = Math.random() * 50;

    //randomly scale the x and y
    var ranScale:Number = Math.random() * 3;
    target.scaleX = ranScale;
    target.scaleY = ranScale;

    var tween:String;
    // ranScale is between 0.0 and 1.0
    if (ranScale < 1) {
        tween = "slow";

    // ranScale is between 1.0 and 2.0
    } else if (ranScale < 2) {
        tween = "medium";

    // ranScale is between 2.0 and 3.0
    } else {
        tween = "fast";

    }
    //assign tween nested in myClip
    myClip[tween].addTarget(target);

}

sentences_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,  fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(5);
}

button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_2);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(20);
}
```

Every time I move to a new keyframe I get this error and I do not know how to correct it. Can someone please help me? Thank you.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/randomInterval()
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at SetIntervalTimer/onTimer()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I don't agree with you about `randomInterval`, because it's the function which is executed by the `setTimeout` and where the error is fired. To Marianna : I think that the problem is in this line : `myClip[tween].addTarget(target);`, your called object should be available in the keyframe where you want to go.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. @akmozo I only want the scripted rain in the first keyframe and when I will move to a new keyframe I want it to stop. How can i remove it  when the sentences_btn and button3 are clicked;

Comment: @Marianna To avoid that error, you have to clear all your Timeouts before going to another keyframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Most likely* what causes a null reference is the line `myClip[tween].addTarget(target);`, as @akmozo pointed in comments.

I would guess, that when you go to another keyframe, `myClip` is no longer available. So, you have two choices: 1 -- extend `myClip` to keyframes in question, so it keeps raining there, or 2 -- stop the rain by cancelling timeouts. To do the latter you need to save timeouts ids somewhere, so you can cancel them later. The code below illustrates the idea.

```
// Number of symbols to add.
const NUM_SYMBOLS:uint = 175;

var symbolsArray:Array = [];
var timeouts:Array = []; // -- list of timeouts
var idx:uint;
var drop:Rain;

for (idx = 0; idx < NUM_SYMBOLS; idx++) {
    drop = new Rain();
    addChild(drop);
    symbolsArray.push(drop);

    // Call randomInterval() after 0 to a given ms.
    // -- add timeout id to list
    timeouts.push(
        setTimeout(randomInterval, int(Math.random() * 10000), drop)
    );
}

// -- call this method to stop the rain, when you change keyframes
function stopRain() : void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i<timeouts.length; i++) {
        clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Nox Noctis! That was the answer to my problem.